# Apache server only responds to external IP

Tags: apache-2.2, django

I am learning Django and wanted to test hosting it on an Ubuntu computer I have. I decided to serve it with Apache and mod_wsgi. I got most things working, but I have one thing puzzling me. I can access the website only from my external IP address, not from say 127.0.0.1 or my 192.168.x.x address.

My django.conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/username/project

ServerName my_external_ip

Alias /media/ /home/username/project/media
Alias /static/ /home/username/project/static

<Directory /home/username/project>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

If I set ServerName to 127.0.0.1 then the page only loads from there. Also I should add, it doesn't exactly "not load" when I access from other locations, it just shows an Apache page titled "Index of /" with no contents.

What is stopping Apache serving pages in all cases, and how can I make it serve pages as 127.0.0.1 etc..? Is there a better way I should host it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer lies in `apache2ctl -S` - the "default" site from the install takes precedence when the `Host` header that the HTTP client sends doesn't match a `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` in one of the other `<VirtualHost>` blocks on the port.

If you want your Django site to be handling all requests to the server, then disable the default:

```
a2dissite default
```

...then restart Apache.

Otherwise, if you want to be a little more nuanced about having Django take over, you can add a `ServerAlias` to the config of its `<VirtualHost>`:

```
ServerAlias internal.ip external.ip external.dns.name
```